# The `Texas` Tag

Tags: discussion, tag-blacklist-request

How did we end up with a [texas](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/texas) tag?
Can we please burninate it?

I'm guessing that it's being used to refer to parts made by TI.

Comment: As a fellow Texan, I find this offensive (just kidding, I know what you're talking about LOL). It is a weird name for a tag. Should National Instruments have it's own "nation" tag? :P

Answer (score 14):

Actually, there are several manufacturer tags, including [atmel](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atmel), [nxp](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nxp) and [microchip](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microchip).

So I went ahead and created [texas-instruments](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/texas-instruments) and merged [texas](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/texas) into it, since "Texas" by itself doesn't make sense as a tag.

Comment: Note that there is also the [tag:ti] tag, which has the majority of the Texas Instruments questions.

Comment: @W5VO: OK, merged those, too, since "ti" is a bit cryptic.

Comment: *"ti" is a bit cryptic* -- given that it's used as a prefix to the model numbers of most of their consumer-oriented products, I doubt many people would have struggled to understand it...

Comment: I always wondered why there was a titanium tag...

Comment: Given that TI has one of the broadest product lines of all silicon manufacturers, how is the tag even meaningful? I guess it could mean "I won't get any support from the people I buy the parts from,  so I come here instead"...

Comment: @Lundin I've worked with TI recently on several projects, and that is an accurate and justifiable statement.  The last time I opened a ticket with them, they left me hanging for about 6 weeks and then responded to ask if they could close the ticket.

Answer (score 12):

Generally, I would say that all manufacturer tags should be avoided. Because all those companies tend to merge and split like crazy.

**Tags should be about the *product family*, not the manufacturer.**

For example, use [avr](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avr) not [atmel](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atmel). Because suddenly Atmel goes poof and ceases to exist. Also the tag [atmel](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atmel) is too broad since they have/had multiple product lines, so it doesn't really add anything meaningful.

For reference, the stance over at SO is to burninate all company name tags, especially if they have ambivalent meanings.

Comment: You can certainly encourage people use product family tags, but there will still be those who use a manufacturer tag anyway, so it might as well exist. It seems that most newcomers don't read the descriptions of the tags they use.

Comment: It would be helpful if there were a way to flag tags as "manufacturer" tags, and use of such tags would trigger a warning prompting the user to also find the appropriate product family tag (e.g. `avr`, `regulator`, `op-amp`)

Comment: @DaveTweed Yeah but since people don't read the tag descriptions, it would be better if the manufacturer tags didn't exist at all. But of course it is a major project to get rid of them, lots of work in comparison to the benefits.

Comment: @DoktorJ That's actually a very good idea, especially if users could create the association between a manufacturer tag and product tags. Many SE sites would benefit from that, not just EE. Might be a good suggestion to bring up with SE now, since they are working on the new "ask a question wizard".

Comment: I now made a suggestion to have this integrated in the new wizard [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/370272/584518). I think this would be a great feature for EE and SO both.

Comment: @Lundin thanks for submitting that -- I'm mostly just a regular SE user who periodically wanders into meta and has no clue what I'm looking at, and had no clue where to begin with that!

Comment: Basically Stack Overflow acts as guinea pig for all new features before they hit the whole of the SE network.

Comment: @DoktorJ At Code Review, we'd be interested in such a system as well. [Been for a while, really](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2090/52915).