# Merging [Atmel] and [Microchip]

Tags: discussion, tags

[This answer](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6625/53368) to the question about the [texas](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/texas) tag mentioned that other tags such as [atmel](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atmel) and [microchip](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microchip) both exist.

Given that [Microchip acquired Atmel](http://www.microchip.com/announcements/microchip-technology-inc-acquires-atmel) a couple of years back, should we merge the two tags?

Comment: I think it will be a very long time before people stop tagging AT chips as Atmel, as they are very strongly flavoured. If you merge them now, proposals for new Atmel tags may start showing up soon enough. Though I don't particularly have an opinion either way. In the last 60 days there were as many new Atmel questions as there were new Microchip questions dealing with an Atmel part.

Comment: @Asmyldof: The [tag:atmel] tag wouldn't disappear; it would become a "synonym" for [tag:microchip]. It's probably a good idea to merge them, but I'll wait a bit to see if there are any contrary opinions.

Answer (score 6):

Let's not merge them just yet. One of the [good points Lundin brings up](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6626/638) is that the tags shouldn't necessarily be targeting a manufacturer, but a product line. Many people have used the manufacturer (Atmel) as a proxy for the product line (AVR), and I don't want to lose that information through a merge.

I think a synonym is a good idea (e.g. no new [atmel](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atmel) tags), but let's not merge them yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is beneficial to keep them separate, most people don't call a pic an atmel part in conversation (yet). The designators/part numbers have also not changed, so leave them separate for the time being.