# Policy for redundant or "umbrella" tags

Tags: discussion, tags

A user just added [microchip](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microchip) to everything tagged [pic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pic). I and other reviewers rejected this, because things tagged [pic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pic) is already inherently about microchip, so in this case it serves little or no purpose.

A couple of other reviewers acted differently, so some of these tag edits got through.

What's the actual policy here, or if there isn't one - what do we want it to be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The \`Texas\` Tag](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6624/the-texas-tag)

Comment: @Lundin The other question asks why there is a 'texas' tag, which is a state in the US. It doesn't apply here.

Comment: That's not why. It's a useless manufacturer tag that should be removed, just like Microchip.

Comment: Definitely not a duplicate

Answer (score 2):

In this instance, they should probably be rejected as Microchip now own both AVR and PIC. Tagging as `microchip` makes searching harder as it would combine both AVR and PIC questions.

In general, however, umbrellas terms are probably quite useful to get started when looking for previous questions if you don't know precisely what you should be searching for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem with this, even though it's redundant, there isn't any harm done and it makes a slightly more searchable for bots or whatever else is looking for the question on the internet

Comment: I agree, so long as it doesn't bump potentially more useful tags off because of the maximum allowed.

Comment: No, the manufacturer name adds absolutely nothing and it is harmful. We already knew that Microchip makes PIC. "No harm done" yeah right. Did you just volunteer to clean up the 388 questions tagged [tag:atmel]? See the problem here?

Comment: @Lundin, but not every person trying to search the site will be thinking "This is a PIC device". Some of them will be thinking "This is a Microchip device". We should only make their lives harder if there's a really good reason/technical limitation/etc why we can't make things easier for them.

Comment: @ThePhoton By using that flawed logic, we also need a tag "electronics". That's not how tags work. Tags should describe what a question is about, not about what it contains. "Microchip" could mean anything from a CAN transceiver to flash memories to Atmel ARM and AVR families. It could even mean PIC. Stack Overflow already has a policy to get rid of company tags since many years, because they are facing the very same problem as EE.